# WebStorm auto vs relative imports in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I switched to WebStorm from VSCode a bit ago and I'm loving it. I only wish auto-imports would work the same way they’ve always worked for me in VSCode: relative imports for sibling and child imports, otherwise absolute imports. Let’s say I have this directory tree in a TypeScript app (React in my exact case).

```text
app/
  components/
  pages/
```

If I’m in `app/pages/profile` and I import a button component, it should import from `app/components/Button`. But if I’m in `app/components/Button` and need to import `app/components/Icon`, it should import from `./Icon`.

In VSCode this just works, but I can’t for the life of me figure out how to do this in WebStorm. It will either do absolute 100% of the time or relative 100%, depending on my configuration.

Has anyone else run into this problem and know how to fix it? I've tried all of the "use path mappings from tscong.json" options.

[image]

And my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": [
        "src/app/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./.eslintrc.js",
    "dist",
    ".jest",
    "./src/**/*.stories.*"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./scripts/generateServiceWorker.js",
    "./src/**/**/*",
    "./webpack.*.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It should work with Use path mappings from tsconfig.json set to Only in files outside specified paths 
If it doesn't work as expected, please share a sample repo that reproduces the issue